How to change bearings on huffy rock it
How can I Change the crank bearings on huffy rock it. Childs bike.

It’s difficult to do more than speculate without photos.

Can you post a clear photo of the crank drive side area including the bottom bracket.

The Huffy Rock It comes in both a 12", 16" and 20" wheel version.
All versions have a one-piece crank and standard one-piece crank removal instructions do apply.
Here are Huffy's instructions on one-piece cranks.
There are lots of videos on this
Summarizing just the removal process:
If you have a chainguard remove it.

Remove the pedal - 1/2" or 13 mm wrench - left hand thread - clockwise loosens
Remove the locknut 1 1/8 inch wrench, I use channel locks - left hand thread - clockwise loosens
Remove the keyed washer
Remove the adjusting cone using a screwdriver - left hand thread - clockwise loosens - and the left hand bearing
Remove the chain from the sprocket
Turn the crank so that it will slide out (sometimes the right-hand bearing must be removed to get the crank out)

Clean the parts - including the pressed in bearing races - and inspect for damage.
Huffy's instructions contain a useful note:

NOTE. If any of the bearing parts are damaged, you should replace all of the bearing parts They are usually sold as a set. Make sure the new parts match the old pans

You would need to use a hammer and punch to remove the pressed in bearing races.
It would be best if the parts were not damaged and you could just re-assemble the bike with clean lubrication and correct adjustment. Since these bikes are made of poor quality materials and usually assembled at the factory with all bearings much too tight there is a high chance that the bearings and or bearing surfaces are badly damaged.
I'm not sure where to find the correct parts should you need them.
Since all bearings and bearing surfaces are replaceable it would not hurt to re-assemble, adjust best possible and keep riding until you find the right parts - if the parts are even remotely usable.
